# How to avoid Add this or me qualification issue in visual studio 2017 15.9.13

Tags: visual-studio-2017

How can we resolve the below error. Same code works without any errors in previous visual studio versions. Only after upgrading I am getting this error. It is not possible to add 'this' to all the properties across the big solution. Hence is there any easy away we are avoid this error.

[image]

Comment: What is the code which causes the problem?  Is this an *error* or simply a suggestion of some kind?  What's the actual error?  Did you try adding `this` (C#) or `Me` (VB) as suggested?

Comment: @David After adding this it works fine. But cannot add it to all the 900 files in the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Made changes to editor config file and it started working.

```
# Remove the line below if you want to inherit .editorconfig settings from higher 
directories
root = true

# C# files
[*.cs]

# this. and Me. preferences
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = false:silent
dotnet_style_qualification_for_property = false:silent
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method = false:silent
dotnet_style_qualification_for_event = false:silent
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Resharper and found that Visual Studio (2019) was adding the `this` qualifier on code completion which would then trigger resharper's `Remove redundant 'this' qualifier` suggestion.

For some reason updating these settings via the gui (Reshaper nor Visual Studio settings) did not have any effect. Updating the `.editorconfig` however worked immediately for me. Thanks @Deepak!.

- To disable suggestions and code completion from adding `this` qualifier.

```
# "This." and "Me." qualifiers
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_property = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_event = false:suggestion
```

- To enforce set to true and select the desired severity. Either `true:warning` or `true:error`.

See [Language conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-language-conventions?view=vs-2019#this-and-me)